# How can I pass two types of unlimited variables

Tags: java

How can I pass two types of unlimited variables

```
public static void method(int... x ,  String... y) {                                             

}
//doesn't work
```

Comment: You can't......

Comment: You could try `Object...` but it won't really do what you want.

Comment: You can't. You could pass `List`s instead.

Comment: This is not possible in Java, only the last parameter of a method can have `...`

Comment: You can't using var args... You might want to introduce a parameter object that has var args setters for the `int`s and the `String`s.